# Properly delete QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm new to QT and I'm trying to create and destroy a QThread upon button click (potentially multiple times). I've read through a lot of posts but my Thread either didn't get destroyed or caused a untraceable heap exception within the QMain.dll.

I create my Thread like this:

```
thread = new QThread;
reader = new Reader(); //a QObject subclass
reader->moveToThread(thread);
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), reader, SLOT(read()));
connect(reader, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(threadTimeout()));

connect(reader, SIGNAL(finished()), reader, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(threadFinished()));
```

The Thread then runs in a loop and sends data. The read() function looks like this:

```
void Reader::read() { 
  while(!stop) {
    //... do something ...
  }
  emit finished();
}
```

On Button click I call

```
reader->setStop(true);
```

which breaks the Thread's while-loop. The finished signal is emitted but then a memory exception is triggered. If I remove the two deleteLater() slots no exception is raised but the thread is (obviously) not deleted.

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) in Qt docs. The worker is not connected to `deleteLater`, and the worker `resultReady`, which I assume is the same as your Reader::finished, is connected to the slot `handleResults`, which I assume is the same as your  `threadFinished`. Have a look there and adjust consequently.

Comment: I've tried that but this doesn't delete my thread. In this example thread->quit() and thread->wait() is called within the destructor of main class. I cannot do that because I want to open and close the thread multiple times without ever calling the destructor of the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are deleting the thread object (ie the QThread) while the *thread of execution* is running. In your `threadFinished()`, which is actually task finished, you need to do :

```
 thread->quit();
 thread->wait();
 thread->deleteLater();
 reader->deleteLater();
```

and remove the `finished -> deleteLater` connections.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that but now the execution gets stuck at thread->wait(); any ideas?

Comment: And if I omit the thread->wait() I get the memory exception again.

Comment: There is still an object being executed in that thread. Is `reader` the only one? can you make sure `read()` terminate? It seems it doesnt

Comment: I think the error lies somewhere else. If I remove all code from the while loop, the method proposed by you works well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add connection like this one for [leaving thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#quit) event loop.

```
connect(reader, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
```